# Central Database on QGIS cloud Pro

Tags: qgis, qgis-cloud

I have created a database on QGIS Cloud Pro. I want to share this database with another user for live updates on QGIS desktop. How can I do this?

Comment: you would need to share your api login to do that https://qgiscloud.com/en/pages/quickstart the pro version has "10 PostGIS 2.0 database (max. 500 MB total, max 10 concurrent database connections)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily share the database credentials with other users who will then embed the database into their personal QGIS desktop. How to find out about the database credentials is described in the [QGIS Cloud FAQ](http://support.qgiscloud.com/kb/faq.php?id=4)